# dokan plugin conflict with wpbakery page builder (Visual Composer)

Tags: wordpress, plugins, visual-composer

in my WordPress website i found that **wpbakery page builder** doesn't work correctly while **Dokan** plugin is enabled. 
for example when we add a text block, the editor is not loaded and sometime text block is not loaded at all. when we disable Dokan plugin, it works good.
is it possible to correct such inconsistencies by altering any configuration files ?

Answer (score 1):

better you contact with the Dokan plugin support, they can help u.
https://wedevs.com/dokan/